# Can we use SQL Server 2016 Polybase without Azure?

Tags: polybase

I am trying to find a sample where i can see end to end installation of SQL Server 2016 polybase on local machine which connects to Hadoop not on Azure.

Comment: Is this link and the links at the bottom of the page what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide

Answer (score 0):

You can find that documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/get-started-with-PolyBase